# Overwrite self in load method of class

Tags: python, oop, object, pickle

Let's say I have the following python class

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, A):
        self.A = A
```

I want to create a load and save methods, but overwriting self will not actually save the loaded instance:

```py
class A:
    ...
    def load(self, filename):
        with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
            new_A = pickle.load(file)
        self = new_A
```

One alternative I can think of is manually overwriting all attributes. This seems like a hassle when expanding the class in the future.

```py
class A:
    ...
    def load(self, filename):
        with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
            new_A = pickle.load(file)
        self.A = new_A.A
```

Is there an easier way to achieve the same results?

Comment: `self` is just a local variable. I also agree that this doesn't make sense as an instance method, it should just be a module-level function or a classmethod, maybe. But if you really want to keep it as is, you can just do something like `self.__dict__.update(new_A.__dict__)` Although, if there are attributes that may not exist, you might want to do `self.__dict__.clear(); self.__dict__.update(new_A.__dict__)`

Answer (score 1):

Assigning to `self` is like assigning to *any* local variable; it does not affect the value previously assigned to `self`.

What you want is a *class* (or static) method that creates an object from the pickle file.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    @classmethod
    def load(cls, filename):
        with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
            return pickle.load(file)
```

Since/if `cls` isn't actually used, you can use a static method instead:

```
    @staticmethod
    def load(filename):
        with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
            return pickle.load(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@staticmethod
def load(filename):
   with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
        new_A = pickle.load(file)
   return new_A
```

This creates a static method that does not take `self` as an argument. Instead it returns a new instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to work:

```
import pickle

class A:
    def __init__(self, A):
        self.A = A

    def write(self, filename):
        with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
            pickle.dump(self, file);

    def load(self, filename):
        with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
            new_A = pickle.load(file)
        self.__dict__ = new_A.__dict__


x = A("test")
y = A(4)
x.write("ff1.dmp")
y.write("ff2.dmp")
x.load("ff2.dmp")
print(x.A)   # 4
```